# How to trigger a python selenium script when an email with a specific subject arrives in my outlook mailbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, outlook, win32com

I am  using outlook version Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2208 Build 16.0.15601.20644) 64-bit .

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Outlook (or connect to the running Outlook instance if it is already running because Outlook is a singleton) where you could handle the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. Use the Entry ID represented by the `EntryIDCollection` string to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item, for example, check the `Subject` property and then call a script if required..

You may find the [Automating Outlook using Python win32com](https://github.com/Hridai/Automating_Outlook) code sample helpful.